# Landsat 8 dataset processing in batch?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, envi, landsat-8

I´m trying to open Landsat images at Geotiff with metadata in ENVI.

I have a dataset of 101 Landsat 8 images and I want to open all the images and then save them to do some band math either on ArcGIS for Desktop or ENVI.

Any idea in how can I do this task for the all batch at once?

I´m doing this to calculate the Normal Difference Snow Index (NDSI).

Comment: So what's the error, what about this isn't working? Are you trying to mosaic them or just convert the format?

Comment: In ArcGIS you need to use the Model Builder with Iterate Rasters and various bits of Map Algebra. ENVI is not really suited for this kind of work without diving into IDL-scripting.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I'm trying to apply all at once to all images.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Any idea of where can I find a IDL scripting tutorial or do you know how to do it?

Comment: What's the function(s)? Is it something that *can* be done in ArcGis with Spatial Analyst? Esri would be better for iteration than ENVI... so let's see if we can make a model for this. I've done NDVI in Esri, but being in Queensland (Australia) we have absolutely no call for snow index, therefore I'm not aware of the method to calculate this snow index.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson The index is very similar. It use the green and the SWIR bands of Landsat 8. I can do the math functions in ArcGis but I can´t compose all the images at once with the metadata in ENVI or Arcgis. I don´t know a function to do this in ArcGis or how to do it with the IDL of ENVI.

Comment: @jpdelped I don't really use IDL myself, so I can't actually tell a good tutorial from a bad one. I would in general suggest that you rely on ArcGIS for a small task like this. If the fact that the Landsat images are separated into single band rasters causes issues, you can look at creating VRTs (virtual rasters) with GDAL. These are quick and easy to make, and ArcGIS can work with them.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for you by using ENVI and timeseries analysis

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/TimeSeriesTutorial.html

Comment: I tried but I can't export each image or do band's math with this option. I have to process the images and then create shapefiles for each image with the snow cover. Do you know a way to do this with the time series? I have tried write a script with IDL but I don't manage the language, it is very tricky and different from Python.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.  They become defunct when the link does.  More details on SE policy for link only answers available here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers